# Help with Kaluza-Klein Christoffel symbols

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, kaluza-klein

For

\begin{align}
\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu\nu} & = \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda X} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu X} + \partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\mu X} - \partial_X \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu\sigma} + \partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda5} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{\nu5} + \partial_\nu \tilde{g}_{\mu 5} - \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}\right)
\end{align}

where

\begin{cases}
\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} = g_{\mu\nu} + k A_\mu A_\nu \\
\tilde{g}_{\mu5} = k A_\mu \\
\tilde{g}_{55} = k\,(\mathrm{constant})
\end{cases}

and

\begin{cases}
\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu} = g^{\mu\nu} \\
\tilde{g}^{\mu5} = -A_\mu \\
\tilde{g}^{55} = \frac{1}{k} + A_\mu A^\mu.
\end{cases}

If I want to calculate $\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu 5}$, I will write

\begin{align}
\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu 5} & = \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda X} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5 X} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu X} - \partial_X \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5\sigma} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda5} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{55} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu5} - \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}

Is it then correct to write that eq. $(1)$ reduces to

$$\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu 5}=\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right)?$$

Answer (score 0):

You can get pretty close to this conclusion with very simple steps.
\begin{align}
\tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu 5} & =\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5\sigma} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda5} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{55} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu5} - \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5\sigma} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right) + \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda5} \partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{55}  \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5\sigma} + \partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right)
\end{align}
The second line uses $x - x = 0$ while the third line uses the fact that $k$ is constant. There is now only one more term we might wish to cancel:
\begin{align}
\partial_5 \tilde{g}_{\mu\nu} = 0 \,\, \Rightarrow \,\, \tilde{\Gamma}^\lambda_{\mu 5} = \frac{1}{2} \tilde{g}^{\lambda\sigma} \left(\partial_\mu \tilde{g}_{5\sigma} - \partial_\sigma \tilde{g}_{\mu 5}\right).
\end{align}
This is an extra assumption which is usually called the cylinder condition. It is definitely not the case that any metric of the above form needs to be constant with respect to $x_5$.

Instead, the cylinder condition is something that should be corrected order-by-order when the radius of the $x_5$ space is small. The metric and other fields should be expanded in $\exp(2\pi i x_5 / r)$ plane waves or more generally spherical harmonics. Ignoring $x_5$ corresponds to keeping the lowest KK mode. As you include the higher modes, the equations of motion pick up larger and larger mass terms and the situation becomes identical to that of effective field theory with heavy particles.